# JS animation from zero to current amount

Tags: javascript, html, css

Everytime I click the button it add +10(counter) width.
I want the animation to go from width 0 to "counter" width everytime i click the button, but it always starts from last position.
I want the animation to go from 0px to "counter" px
Do you please know how to solve it? Thank you :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  * {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  #demo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f00;
    transition: width 1s ease;
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="demo">
  <br><br><br>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">TRY</button>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
counter = 0;
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.width="0px";
    counter+=10;
    document.getElementById("demo").style.width=counter+"px";
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You have `#demo { width: 100px; }` try removing it

Comment: Reset the counter each time inside your function

Comment: Move `counter=0` inside the function...?

Comment: Thanks, but if I reset the counter it will never more add +10px. It would be always 10px width

Comment: I want the animation to go from 0px to "counter" px

Comment: This seems to be working fine - Can you please clarify the issue you're having? [Here is your code, copy+pasted into JSFiddle without any edits.](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/z7oe1u2f/) **EDIT:** Move your script *into* your `<body>` tags.

Comment: Yes it is working but not as I wanted. The animation is incerasing by 10 everytime, but I want it to go from 0 (no width) to coutner width.

Comment: Oh, understood. As the answer below states, setting the width to `counter` is happening too quickly after setting it to `0px`, so it's essentially just skipping the `0px` portion. You can add a `setTimeout()` to delay it a little bit, and ensure that it has time to get set to `0px` before setting it to `counter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` with `duration` set to same as `css` `transition`, call `document.getElementById("demo").style.width = counter + "px";` within `setTimeout()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      font-size: 50px;
    }
    #demo {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #f00;
      transition: width 1s ease;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="demo">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">TRY</button>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  counter = 0;

  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.width = "0px";
    counter += 10;
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("demo").style.width = counter + "px";
    }, 1000)
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Beat me to answering. Yes, timeout is the correct solution

Comment: And is there a way to make it instant to 0px? Not to animate to it slowly. After clicking button it will not go back (decrease) with animation to 0 - but just increase with animation.

Comment: You can `unset` the `transition` property at `click` event, then reset `transition` at `setTimeout` http://plnkr.co/edit/T5bgniQrTLxnx98HnWrP?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution (also using `setTimeout()`) is to use the timeout to "animate" the movement, rather than using the CSS animation. The reason for doing this is that the animation from the full width down to 0 will not be animated, which I personally think is goofy. The other reason is that **`setTimeout` is not guaranteed to run at your specified interval** -- it is guaranteed to run **at least** every n milliseconds. This *can* produce timing issues with the CSS animation causing them to not be synced up and produce strange results.

The cons of this solution is that if the user spams the "try" button, you get flashes of the different widths, and for smaller values of `counter`, it feels a bit choppier. It smooths out nicely as counter gets larger, though.

Give this a try and see if it works better for you.

```js
counter = 0;

function myFunction() {
  var startingValue = 0;
  var currValue = 0;
  document.getElementById("demo").style.width = "0px";
  counter += 10;

  function timeout() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      currValue += 10;
      document.getElementById("demo").style.width = currValue + "px";
      if (currValue < counter) {
        timeout();
      }
    }, 30);
  }
  timeout();
}
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 50px;
}
#demo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">TRY</button>
</div>
```